# Regarding jquery floating point calculation

Tags: jquery

In the jquery animate function  have the below code.  newleft variable contains the
incorrect values after the addition.  Not sure whether i am doing the right way.

```
  step: function( now, fx ) {

    if(fx.prop==="left") {
       var newleft= $("p").offset().left+ now;
     }
     $("p").css("left",newleft)
   }
```

Comment: CSS left property should have a unit, e.g. "px", "em", etc.

Comment: $("p").css("left",newleft + "px")

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  jsfiddle.net/hLYJD newleft should have 400-200 =200px at the end of animation but it's getting strange values like 2382.546875.  This is before css function.

Comment: could any one help to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`now` will always be the **absolute** value of the property, it is **not relative** to the previous step.
That means you have to subtract `now` from the *original* position of the `p` element, not its current position:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var a = $("p").offset().left; // get original position

    $("div").animate({left: '-200px'}, {
        step: function (now, fx) {

            if (fx.prop === "left") {
                var b = now;
                var newleft = a + b;
                $("body").append("<div>" + a + "::::::" + b + "------" + newleft + "</div>");
                $("p").css("left", newleft + "px");
            }

        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hLYJD/1/

This only works because the `div` is positioned at `0`. If it were positioned differently, you have to subtract the `div`'s original position from `now` first, to get the relative movement:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var a = $("p").offset().left;
    var b = $("div").offset().left;

    $("div").animate({left: '-200px'}, {
        step: function (now, fx) { 
            if (fx.prop === "left") {
                var newleft = a + (now - b);
                $("p").css("left", newleft + "px");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hLYJD/2/

---

But if all you want to do is move both elements by the same relative amount, then just use `-=200` as animation value:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $("div, p").animate({left: '-=200'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Didn't know about using the simple way of doing it.   $("div, p").animate({left: '-=200'});  Thanks a lot for your time and explanation.

Comment: I am unable to award the 200+ bounty to you now as I am getting a message I need to wait for 20 hours.  Will do it later.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `px` in your `newleft` variable:

```
var newleft= $("p").offset().left+ now + "px";
```

or append `px` when you set `left` value of your paragraph:

```
$("p").css("left",newleft + "px")
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  When i print the newleft value getting incorrect value before $("p").css function. addition of  "px" doesn't correct it.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to replicate your problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hLYJD/     newleft should have 400-200 =200px at the end of animation but it's getting strange values  like 2382.546875